# vaadin add-on diagram builder, widgetset.nocache.js not found

Tags: vaadin, add-on

I have problem integrating diagram-builder add-on into vaadin 7 project. I put all 3 downloaded jars into WEB-INF/lib directory, along with com.fasterxml.jackson.*.jar libs. After successful compilation, I run the project on a tomcat server and encounter the following pop-up window:

Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/org.vaadin.diagrambuilder.WidgetSet/org.vaadin.diagrambuilder.WidgetSet.nocache.js?1405669571852 .

Relevant code snippet:

```
    private void initDiagram()
{
    // Initialize our new UI component
    DiagramBuilder diagramBuilder = new DiagramBuilder();
    diagramBuilder.setAvailableFields(new NodeType("diagram-node-start-icon", "Start", "start"),
                                      new NodeType("diagram-node-fork-icon", "Fork", "fork"),
                                      new NodeType("diagram-node-condition-icon",
                                                   "Condition",
                                                   "condition"));
    diagramBuilder.setFields(new Node("StartNode", "start", 10, 10), new Node("Condition",
                                                                              "condition",
                                                                              260,
                                                                              16));

    diagramBuilder.setTransitions(new Transition("StartNode", "Condition", "TaskConnector1"));

    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);

    layout.addComponent(diagramBuilder);

}
```

I also added necessary annotation necessary for the usage of vaadin widget.

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VtUI.class, widgetset="org.vaadin.diagrambuilder.WidgetSet")
```

Did I miss something? Do you have an idea of how to solve this? Any help is appreciated! My project can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6hwsh384otdjsc/vt.zip)  .

I have searched through the web with no luck. My project is very simple, no maven is involved. Since I have followed the recommended way of integrating vaadin add-on (please let me know if I have missed anything), this might be a common problem.

[EDIT]

With the help of @cfrick and @André Schild, I am able to integrate diagram builder to my vaadin project. But when I run the project, I still cannot see the diagram builder in the browser. At the same time, I observed some error using Firebug as follows:

```
SEVERE: Exception caught: (TypeError) : $wnd.YUI is not a functioncom.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : $wnd.YUI is not a function
at Unknown.Fg(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Mg(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Zt(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.au(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.xt(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.crb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Wnb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Qnb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.xmb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.ymb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.vmb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Rmb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Vlb(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.cj(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Wi(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.gj(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.aj(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.vi(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.Ai(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source) Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : $wnd.YUI is not a function
```

I reckon it is something wrong with javascript somewhere. Any ideas/hints would be greatly appreciated!

**[SOLVED]**

Please check out Matti's response here https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/7846087 . It is the problem of not having injected the alloyi script to the host page.

Thanks for all your help! :-) 
Cheers, X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the wrong widgetset here:

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VtUI.class, widgetset="org.vaadin.diagrambuilder.WidgetSet")
```

It should be

```
com.seeburger.vt.widgetset.VtWidgetset
```

**EDIT**:

the UI class lacked annotations for alloyui, like:

```
@JavaScript("http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.5.0/aui/aui-min.js")
@StyleSheet("http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.5.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Comment: I just tried out your comment, i.e., use "com.seeburger.vt.widgetset.VtWidgetset" instead of "org.vaadin.diagrambuilder.WidgetSet", but I still cannot load this addon as it is shown in the tutorial as of http://matti.app.fi/diagram-builder-demo/ .

Comment: any new/other error now, with the proper widgetset?

Comment: thanks for your comments, they are one step further in the right direction. But the diagram builder add-on cannot be loaded. When I took a look using Firebug, I get the following error:

Comment: "Mon Jul 21 13:37:27 GMT+200 2014 com.vaadin.client.VConsole
SEVERE: Exception caught: (TypeError) : $wnd.YUI is not a functioncom.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : $wnd.YUI is not a function
 at Unknown.Cj(Unknown Source)
......
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : $wnd.YUI is not a function

Comment: could you please make an edit to your question, note the changes and put the whole error there too?  but the error indicates YUI (yahoo js library) is missing.  does the diagram builder need it (and therefor should bring in dep dependency?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile the widgetset and specify it to be used

https://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons

> Important If the add-on has any custom client-side code (i.e. contains
>   a *.gwt.xml file defining a widget set), your application must define
>   a single widget set that inherits from the add-on widget sets in your
>   project. See the links below for more details on how this is
>   accomplished.

Probably you did miss to specify your own widgetset

Comment: I did recompile the widgetset of the project, but this does not solve the problem. :-(

Comment: This message indicates that you either have not compiled the widgetset or/and did not provide your own widgetset. I have enhanced my first answer

Comment: I tried out your comments along with @cfrick's. I am able to load some other addons, like Vaadin Calendar. But still in the case of diagram-builder, nothing really works.